# $firebaseArray not returning expected value

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to get a `$firebaseArray` but rather than the array I'm expecting, I'm getting an array/object of `length` 0. The object contains properties like `$$added`, `$error`, `$getKey`, etc., but none of the data I expect.

**The strangest part is that this exact same code functions properly on a different computer running the same code.**

Here's my code (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory('Props', ['$rootScope', '$firebaseArray', 'Refs', function($rootScope, $firebaseArray, Refs) {
  var service = {
    // initialized below
    user: null,

    init: function(user) {
      this.user = user;
      if (user) {
        this.user.feed = $firebaseArray(Refs.feed(user.email));
        $firebaseArray(Refs.props).$loaded(function(props) {
          this.user.props = props;
          console.log(props);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

When I do an `ng-repeat` over `this.user.props`, it's blank (but only on my computer). When I do `console.log(props)`, it has a `length` of 0 (but only on my computer).

What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption for your error is the following line:

```
this.user.props = props;
```

I take it this is happening because you are including `this` which doesn't mean the same thing now that you're inside of a callback function.

You might want to change a few things here.  You may not want to call your function parameter `user`, but instead something else otherwise it could cause a lot of confusion.

Let me know if something like this works:

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory('Props', ['$rootScope', '$firebaseArray', 'Refs', function($rootScope, $firebaseArray, Refs) {
    var service = {
        // initialized below
        user: null,

        init: function(u) {
            this.user = u;
            if(this.user) {
                this.user.feed = $firebaseArray(Refs.feed(this.user.email));
                $firebaseArray(Refs.props).$loaded(function(props) {
                    user.props = props;
                    console.log(props);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Regards,